# VBA RESTful API GET Method issue

Tags: vba, asp.net-web-api, get, winhttprequest

Hi I'm calling an API and using the winhttp request and the GET method. I'm passing a json style parameter in the send method but it just can't get accepted. I end up with the error message:

{"code":"INS03","description":"Event ID required","requestId":"_181603230829162847306080","data":{},"validationErrors":null}

Which seems weird because I am indeed passing the event id parameter, as follows:

```
    inventory_URL = "https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v1"

    Dim oRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim sResult As String

    Set oRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    With oRequest
        .Open "GET", inventory_URL, True
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & access_token
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "application/json"
        .send ("{""eventid"":""9445148""}")
        .waitForResponse
        sResult = .responseText
        Debug.Print sResult
        sResult = oRequest.Status
        Debug.Print sResult
   End With
```

Is there any issue with my code?

Thank you in advance,

Vadim

Comment: I don't think it's going to change anything, but the parentheses around `.send ("{""eventid"":9445148}")` should be removed. See [this is confusing. why not just use parentheses all the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201608231909481978335) on Docs.SO for why this is eventually going to bite you in the rear end if you make it a habit.

Comment: Have you tried `.send "9445148"`? What does the API documentation says the URL is expecting?

Comment: I agree about the parentheses, also the pure .send "944518" might work, i didn't exactly do that but i found a work around by inserting the parameter directly into the inventory_URL string at the very top. I guess this API supports restful calls so for now i'll keep sticking to that. It's possible the .send "...." is the same technique from a different angle, thanks for the tips I really appreciate it, i'll keep a closer eye on the parenthesis habit !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `GET` request query string should be composed. 
Your data can't be passed in `Send` but in query string:

`.Open "GET", inventory_URL & "?eventid=9445148", True`

Check [GET vs POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Comment: yep that worked as well, i think that's the key issue i was tripping up on, I kept thinking I have to send something but now i see with GET there's no need it'll all be in the url string, thank you